# Error with unit tests in AngularJS - controller with many dependency

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have some problem with unit test in AngularJS. I took from github angular seed app and wrote  some modules. And now when i try to test it I have error.
Problem is only in unit test - in browser app is working correctly.

I feel that it should be something easy to resolve, but I can't find where I make mistake.

My controller:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp.student', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/student', {
    templateUrl: 'student.html',
    controller: 'StudentCtrl'
  });
}])
.controller('StudentCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', '$log', function($scope, $http, $modal, $log) { ... }]);
```

My unit test dokumenty_test.js:

```
describe('myApp.student', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp.student'));

  describe('StudentCtrl controller', function(){

    it('should ....', inject(function($controller) {
      //spec body
      var view1Ctrl = $controller(StudentCtrl');
      expect(view1Ctrl).toBeDefined();
    }));

  });
});
```

And the error from console:
 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scopeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually set up the controller´s dependencies when creating it:

```
it('should ....', inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $http, $modal, $log) {

  var view1Ctrl = $controller('StudentCtrl', {
    '$scope': $rootScope.$new(),
    '$http': $http,
    '$modal': $modal,
    '$log': $log
  });

  expect(view1Ctrl).toBeDefined();
}));
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/IciIZvjRu66P3NhDc6ud

*Note that I added the module `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency to the app since the controller is using `$modal`.*

You can read more about unit testing controllers [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing#testing-a-controller).

Comment: I added dependency ui.bootstrap and in karma.conf.js link to ui.bootstrap: 'https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js' and it work :) Thanks!